R Plumber API: Dealing with query string input that uses array syntax
I'm building a Plumber API that interfaces with output from a survey platform. The survey platform passes variables as a query string appended to the URL redirect.

If the survey question only has one response option (e.g., radio button), it passes that variable in the query string, such as: ?this_var=123456
If the survey question can have multiple response options (e.g., checkbox), it passes that variable in array syntax in the query string with the values of all the selected response options, such as: ?this_var[0]=123&this_var[1]=456&this_var[2]=789

For the first case, I know how to use a @get function to work with the variable in the query string, such as:
#* Echo back the input
#* @param this_var
#* @get /echo
function(this_var=""){
  list(paste0("The message is: '", this_var, "'"))
}

But I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with the second case. At first, I assumed that Plumber would build the vector for me from the query string and I could then access it using the same above syntax, but using the above syntax yields a NULL result for this_var.
I also can't specify the array syntax as an input variable in the function because this leads to a syntax error. The code below won't run because there's a syntax error with an unexpected parenthesis on line 4.
#* Echo back the input
#* @param this_var[0]
#* @get /echo
function(this_var[0]=""){
  list(paste0("The message is: '", this_var[0], "'"))
}

How do I access these array syntax query string variables in a Plumber API?
